# How to tell if data checksum feature is on in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Postgres 9.3 introduces a data checksum feature which can detect corruption in pages.  Is there a way to query the database to determine if this is on?

Being hosted on a PaaS system, I don't have access to the actual server to check any configurations settings there.  I also only have access to our database and not the main postgres database either. Is there a way to determine if this is on from a psql console only?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
show data_checksums;
 data_checksums 
----------------
 off
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-preset.html

Comment: Do you need special permissions for that maybe? I get "ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "data_checksums"". Also, when I run show all; data_checksums is not in the list

Comment: I would add that ignore_checksum_failure does show up though.

Answer (score 3):

You can use pg_controldata see if your postgresql cluster enable data_checksum.
if version=0 then your cluster disable the function.
And data_checksums parameter add by PostgreSQL 9.3.4, if your postgresql version small than that, you cannt select this guc parameter. you must check it by control file.

```
pg93@db-172-16-3-150-> pg_controldata |grep checksum
Data page checksum version:           0
```

Comment: Aww thanks. My problem is that I am on 9.3.3.  Unfortunately I don't have shell access to the db machine to use pg_controldata.  I guess I just need Heroku to tell me.

Answer (score 3):

From 9.4 on, you can try the following query:

`select * from pg_settings where name ~ 'checksum';`

https://paquier.xyz/postgresql-2/postgres-9-4-feature-highlight-data-checksum-switch-as-a-guc-parameter/